# Combine .Contains and .Like

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I've got a list of search patterns (LIKE) and want to find all items in a table matching to at least one of them. My list would be something like this:

```
string[] searchList = {"mailto:Sam@%", "mailto:info@%", "phone:65331%"};
```

In SQL I would do this:

```
var sqlCommand = "SELECT [Id], [Area]  WHERE [TenantId] = @TenantId AND (";
for (var i = 0; i < searchList.Length; i++)
{
  if (i > 0)
    sqlCommand += " OR ";
  sqlCommand += $"[Area] LIKE search{i}";
  sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue($"search{i}", searchList[i]);
}
sqlCommand += ")";
sqlCmd.CommandText = sqlCommand;
```

Is there any way to achieve this using Linq2Sql? If it would always be three items in the array it would be simple:

```
var result = await context
  .MyTable
  .Where(mt => mt.TenantId == tenantId 
    && (EF.Functions.Like(mt.Area, searchList[0])
     || EF.Functions.Like(mt.Area, searchList[1])
     || EF.Functions.Like(mt.Area, searchList[2])))
```

But of course it might be two items in the searchList. Or four. Or any other number.

I would need some kind of `.Contains` like this, only with LIKE comparison:

```
var result = await context
  .MyTable
  .Where(mt => mt.TenantId == tenantId 
    && searchList.Contains(mt.Area)) // does not work due to wildcards
```

Any way to combine a `.Like` and `.Contains` for these cases?

Or use some kind of loop in the `.Where`-clause?

UPDATE

To use

```
var result = await context
.MyTable
.Where(mt => mt.TenantId == tenantId &&
     searchList.Any(listItem => EF.Functions.Like(mt.Area, listItem)));
```

or

```
var result = await context
.MyTable
.Where(mt => mt.TenantId == tenantId &&
     searchList.Any(listItem => mt.Area.StartsWith(listItem)));
```

is a brilliant idea, but the Linq2Sql-Interpreter ist not able to translate these to SQL queries:

`System.InvalidOperationException: "The LINQ expression 'DbSet<MyTable> .Where(t => t.TenantId == tenantId && __searchList_1 .Any(sl => sl == "" || t.LastName != null && sl != null && t.LastName.StartsWith(sl)))' could not be translated.`

UPDATE 2

I just remembered I could build my SQL query string and use `context.ExecuteQuery<>(sqlCommand)` which would solve my problem.

Comment: FYI, you're "SQL" example is not putting "OR" between the Like statements.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. I interpreted it as you wanted to join with AND and somebody else says OR. Please make it clear.

Comment: Whoops, sorry, added the OR.

Comment: The error message is saying that you are not using LinqToSQL but LinqToEF. Anyway, you need to make second part local. Check my edited reply using OR. BTW, your expression matches to StartsWith, not Contains.

Comment: I think the only way to do this and get it to translate it to SQL and run on the DB is to manually build the `Experssion` which is a messy business. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/how-to-use-expression-trees-to-build-dynamic-queries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`And` (`&&`) conditions are easily emulated by simply chaining multiple `Where` calls.

However LINQ has no integrated support for combining `Or` (`||`) conditions, so you have to use some expression predicate builder library, or performing the desired combination using `Expression` class methods directly.

For top level queries it could be encapsulated in a custom extension method like this:

```cs
public static partial class QueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> WhereAny<T, V>(this IQueryable<T> source, IEnumerable<V> values, Expression<Func<T, V, bool>> match)
    {
        var parameter = match.Parameters[0];
        var body = values
            .Select(value => Expression.Constant(value, typeof(V)))
            .Select(value => Expression.Invoke(match, parameter, value))
            .Aggregate<Expression>(Expression.OrElse);
        var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, parameter);
        return source.Where(predicate);
    }
}
```

and the usage in your case would be:

```cs
var result = await context.MyTable
    .Where(mt => mt.TenantId == tenantId) 
    .WhereAny(searchList, (mt, s) => EF.Functions.Like(mt.Area, s))
    .ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can

`using System.Linq;`

```
var result = await context.MyTable
                          .Where(entry => mt.TenantId == tenantId && 
                                 searchList.Any(listItem => mt.Area.StartsWith(listItem, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)));
```

Comment: Brilliant idea, but linq does not like it. 
System.InvalidOperationException: "The LINQ expression 'DbSet<MyEntity>
    .Where(t => t.TenantId == locals1_tenantId_0 && __searchList_1
        .Any(sl => __Functions_2
            .Like(
                _: t.LastName, 
                matchExpression: sl)))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly 
Client eval would be bad, any idea how to rewrite it so it works as SQL?

Comment: you could also try  this await context
  .MyTable.Where(entry => mt.TenantId == tenantId && searchList.Any(listItem => mt.Area.StartsWith(listItem, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))) BUT you have to remove the wildcard '%' from your list of string

Comment: Using `.StartsWith` instead of `.Like` does throw the very same error, is not supported in translation in Linq2Sql.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `String Contains` is supported and also iterate over array with `Any`

```
var result = await context.MyTable
  .Where(mt => mt.TenantId == tenantId && searchList.Any(a => a.Contains(mt.Area))
```

Beware not all the overloads of Contains are supported in LINQ to SQL,

Next time please tell us what .NET and EF version do you use, There are diffrences between .Net Core, EF Core and EF 6.

Comment: The OPs values already have the wildcards, so they don't want `string.Contains`, but based on the location of the wildcards if they are removed, it looks like `string.StartsWith` might be a better option.

Comment: as @juharr said I can't use `string.Contains` - I might be able to work with `.StartsWith`, but the LINQ interpreter is not able to handle the query:
`System.InvalidOperationException: "The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Entity>
    .Where(t => t.TenantId == locals1_tenantId_0 && __searchList_1
        .Any(sl => sl == "" || t.LastName != null && sl != null && t.LastName.StartsWith(sl)))' could not be translated. `

Comment: I think its because this property navigation t.LastName.StartsWith(sl),
Not everything will be supported inside the Any, but you can check for simple
Any(a => a.StartsWith(mt.Area))

Comment: @AnGG `Any(a => a.StartsWith(mt.Area))` would never match. The parameters of `.StartsWith` cannot be switched for the same result.
And I added EF Core for the version, thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It looks like the way you do it with SQL. result is IQueryable and thus you could chain multiple Where() before sending the query back to server. ie:

```
string[] searchList = {"mailto:Sam@", "mailto:info@", "phone:65331"};

var result = db.MyData.Where( x => x.TenantID = tenantID);

for (var i = 0; i < searchList.Length; i++)
{
  var tmp = searchList[i];
  result = result.Where(x => x.Area.Contains( tmp );
}

// enumerate result here. 
// For example, result.ToList()
```

PS: I assumed you wanted to join them with AND as in your SQL sample.

As @juharr claims you want to connect them with OR. I am not sure. He might be right. Then here you go:

```
string[] searchList = {"mailto:Sam@", "mailto:info@", "phone:65331"};

var result = db.MyData.Where( x => x.TenantID = tenantID)
             .AsEnumerable()
             .Where(x => searchList.Any(se => x.Area.StartsWith(se)));
```

UPDATE: Here is the alternative for server side with OR for completeness:

```
string[] searchList = {"mailto:Sam@%", "mailto:info@%", "phone:65331%"};

var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append($@"select * 
    from MyTable
    where TennantId = {{{searchList.Length}}} and (");

for (int i = 0; i < searchList.Length; i++)
{
    if (i > 0) sb.Append(" or ");
    sb.Append($" Area like {{{i}}}");
}
sb.Append(")");
var query = sb.ToString();

// var tennantId = whatever
Array.Resize(ref searchList, searchList.Length+1);
searchList[searchList.Length-1] = tennantId.ToString();

var result = ctx.ExecuteStoreQuery<Employee>(query, searchList);
```

Comment: They clearly are asking to OR the conditions together, not AND them (note the SQL building code actually doesn't do either one)

Comment: How is this not clear _(EF.Functions.Like(mt.Area, searchList[0])
     OR EF.Functions.Like(mt.Area, searchList[1])
     OR EF.Functions.Like(mt.Area, searchList[2])))_  seems like you're the one that needs to read the question first.

Comment: @juharr, That is how I interpret the SQL. If you want or then you would use something else.

Comment: I edited the question so the SQL part shows the OR as well (I use both, AND and OR)
But anyway, your second solution can not be translated into SQL query (and using client side eval is slooooow) and your first solution does not reflect the OR part

Comment: It is not really slow, if you are not returning too much data with the same tenantID. Otherwise there IS an alternative that I regretted to write now. If you are returning too much data with the same tenantId then let me know and I will write.

Comment: Jup, that "too much data" part is my problem - but it just occured to me that I could use an old fashioned SQL Select and create a LINQ query from that.

Comment: @Sam, Yes, building an SQL query was what I meant as alternative.

Comment: @CetinBasoz I already built one in my example, so it wouldn't be too hard to use that.

Comment: @Sam, yes it is not hard. I added it for completeness sake (I assumed yours was a peudo code).